# error: Platform version is not compatible (XUL runner)

Tags: windows-10, firefox, software-update, xulrunner, microsoft-surface-3

Not sure why I'm getting an [XUL](https://superuser.com/q/490854/55747) error:

```
XUL runner

error:  Platform version '61.0.2' is not compatible with
minVersion >= 61.0.1
maxVersion <= 61.0.1
```

Particularly when this version of Firefox worked fine until not so long ago.  The tablet was powered off.  It's running Windows 10 on a Surface 3.

I can't update through the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have the firefox installer:** 
 1. Delete the Firefox installation directory (profile with settings and addons will not be affected)
 2. Reinstall Firefox

**If you don't have the Firefox installer:** 
 1. Use another browser to download the Firefox installer from the Firefox download page.
 2. Delete the Firefox installation directory (profile with settings and addons will not be affected)
 3. Reinstall Firefox

**Check following links**
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/871959
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2740709